# Can't find id of Angular ui-grid element with Selenium/Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, angular-ui-grid

I have some Protractor tests that are running on an Angular application that uses ui-grid.  I have some working smoke tests for the application, but I am just starting to implement tests using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/test/e2e/gridTestUtils.spec.js to test the ui-grid components.  The problem I'm having is that I need the actual id of the grid element in order to use the `getGrid` function.

I'm able to successfully locate the element using `element(by.css("[id$='-grid-container']"))`, but for some reasons my attempts to get the full id out of the element have failed.  Here is what I am trying:

```
        var grid = element(by.css("[id$='-grid-container']"));
        grid.getAttribute('id').then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            var myGrid = gridTestUtils.getGrid(result.toString());

            gridTestUtils.expectCellValueMatch(myGrid, 0, 0, 'Cox');
        });
```

The `console.log(result);` is not logging anything.  It doesn't SEEM necessarily related to ui-grid, it's just Selenium isn't finding the id for some reason.  As far as I can tell I'm using `getAttribute` correctly; it works with this syntax in other tests, but maybe I'm missing something.  Any ideas why this isn't working?

Edit because my comment is unreadable:

Thanks for the suggestions.  However, I'm still just as confused because

```
    var grid = element(by.css("[id$='-grid-container']"));
    console.log(grid.toString());
    grid.getAttribute('id').then(function(result) {
        console.log('======'+result);
        var myGrid = gridTestUtils.getGrid(result.toString());

        gridTestUtils.expectCellValueMatch(myGrid, 0, 0, 'Cox');
    });
```

gives a console output of

```
[object Object]
======
```

so it seems like the element is being found, which I had already checked, and the console.log inside the promise is being executed.

It's like it can't find the 'id', which according to the API documentation means there is no id on the element.  But that is definitely not true.

Comment: Guessing it might have something to do with the way selenium webdriver handles the escaping css (escapeCss method)? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/by.js Maybe add an ID tag to find it another way?

Comment: The problem is that the ID is being assigned dynamically, and I need to grab it in order to use getGrid.  Changing the design of the web page is not an option, and I am not having issues finding the webElement itself, just grabbing the ID from the element using getAttribute().

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.
However, if your `console.log(result)` doesn't log anything, this means you either didn't find the element or the moment you execute the `getAttribute()` the element is no longer present.

See in the [API description](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute), that `getAttribute()` **always** returns a value, if the element is present.

Maybe try to extend `console.log('======='+result);` to figure out, if that line of code gets executed (I'm pretty sure it's not executed). Also try `console.log(grid.toString());`, which should output `[object Object]`, if the element is really found.

As for the `ElementFinder`, I'm used to use the `'` and `"` just the other way around, so `element(by.css('[id$="-grid-container"]'));` or shorter `$('[id$="-grid-container"]')`.

Let me know, if this helped and you could further determine the cause.

**Round 2**

Let's exclude a few things

1. change `getAttribute('id')` to `getAttribute('outerHTML')` to see,
   if there is anything logged.
2. change `(result)` to `(resultattr)` to exclude, that result is else used by a plugin, who put `result` as a global variable.
3. change `grid.getAttribute()` to be `element(by.css("[id$='-grid-container']")).getAttribute`

What are the results of those actions?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  However, I'm still just as confused because

`var grid = element(by.css("[id$='-grid-container']"));
        console.log(grid.toString());
        grid.getAttribute('id').then(function(result) {
            console.log('======'+result);
            var myGrid = gridTestUtils.getGrid(result.toString());

            gridTestUtils.expectCellValueMatch(myGrid, 0, 0, 'Cox');
        });`

gives a console output of 

`[object Object]`
======

Comment: That comment is impossible to read--I added it to my question.

Comment: It's indeed a strange situation. I now edited my answer with further debugging instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the semantics, but you could try this, just to make sure that you are getting the first element, if multiple:

```
element.all(by.css('[id$="-grid-container"]')).first().getAttribute('id').then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  var myGrid = gridTestUtils.getGrid(result.toString());

  gridTestUtils.expectCellValueMatch(myGrid, 0, 0, 'Cox');
});
```

Comment: I was pretty sure there is only one grid-container on the page (it's a pretty simple app), but I tried your suggestion just to make sure.  No luck.  Thanks for the suggestion, let me know if you have any other idea.